# What's the quickest way to do a "clean" google search?

Tags: seo, google

Currently I'm going into my account settings and switching Web History to off. I then have to go back each time and switch it on again. Is there a quicker way to be able to do a search in Google not tainted by personal results?

Answer (score 4):

In my case i use the incognito-window of my browser. Don't know if it's the best way to do it, but for me it's the quickest.

In Chrome you can press <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> to open a new incognito-window.